# Ember model hook in Route vs Ember.Object.extend({})

Tags: ajax, ember.js

What's the difference between using the model hook in an Ember Route:

```
App.PhotoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/photos/'+params.photo_id);
  }
});
```

Versus creating your own Ember Object?

```
    App.PhotoModel = Ember.Object.extend({});
    App.PhotoModel.reopenClass({
    find: function(id){
       $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.go.get.my.photo',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: { id: id },
      success: function(response){
        return response.data;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is part of the workflow and the other is a class.

The model hook will provide the model for a route when it's accessed (in that case photo).  Additionally it will wait for the async call to complete and use the result of the ajax call.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Extending Ember.Object will define a class for reusability.  It's very much a building block for the entire Ember framework.

```
App.MyModelObject = Ember.Object.extend({});
```

A more useful example would be

```
App.MyModel = Ember.Object.extend({
  total: function(){
    return this.get('val1') + this.get('val2');
  }.property('val1', 'val2')
});

var foo = App.MyModel.create({val1:3, val2:5});

console.log(foo.get('total'));
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xinozi/1/edit

Comment: Does Ember.Object.extend({}) wait for the async to finish also?

Comment: Ember.Object.extend({}) has no asynchronous code, it's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The two are completely different. `model` on an Ember route is a *hook* which ember gives you to (fetch data from an api and create an object that holds the data your controller needs and so on) return a promise which gets resolved to the route's controller's model, when the said route is entered and transitioned into. On the other hand, `App.MyModel = Em.Object.extend({})` creates a class which is just a template from which objects which are instances of `App.MyModel` can be instantiated. 
If your application wanted to model users, for example, it would have a user "model" like

```
App.User = Em.Object.extend({username: 'Alice'})
```

or something similar. However, if you have a user route which looks like `/#/user/id`, then the *model hook* on the route would be something like this

```
model: function(params) {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(success, failure) {
    //make an ajax call and invoke the success and failure handles here appropriately
  });
```

Comment: What is the difference between a hook and a template (class)? Does the hook only occur once in the lifecycle?

Comment: DS.attr wouldn't be defined on an Ember Object.

Comment: @redconservatory Models in your app,(in other words, classes) correspond to the entities in your business logic, the hook on the other hand is the framework's api that provides a "backbone" to your app. The Ember router is a *mechanism* and if you change your framework tomorrow, the mechanism may change, but your models generally don't.